# Why Cold formed steel is becoming important for researchers?

Tags: structural-engineering

A lot of academic research is happening on CFS and it has become very popular in constructions too. Why?

Comment: What is the engineering problem you seeking help from this community?

Comment: Whyt has CFS  attracted so much attention in the circles of academic research?

Comment: The CFS has gained popularity these days due to its light weight, and easier to handle for fast paced construction. However, the light weight advantage comes out from the thinner member thickness, compared to the comparable hot-rolled structural shapes, and the use of lighter but structurally weaker materials. Also, compare to other structural materials, CFS is relatively new, so there are still many areas/concerns to be looked into, in order to utilize it effectively, and confidently.

Answer (score 1):

It is stronger so it can reduce weight with the same strength. Automotive applications in particular make an effort to reduce weight. I expect these are "micro-alloyed" steels , so they are essentially age hardened at the mill ; hot rolling is finished at a particular temperature ,then the hot coil ages as it slowly cools. It has very good cold formability. This has been the standard for line pipe for over 40 years . It has also been used in automotive applications for years . To identify these steels look for small amounts of Nb, Ti, V and possibly other elements. An important feature of this type steel is low carbon so weldability is also excellent.